# Ember computed property adds comma

Tags: javascript, ember.js, computed-properties

I created a computed property to concat two model properties together, and create a list of them. It initially worked like this, which results in a list like so: prop1-prop2, prop1-prop2

```
modelName: Ember.computed(
  return this.get('modelName').map((o) => {
    return o.get('prop1') + '-' + o.get('prop2');
  }).join(', ');
})
```

Then I changed it to this which results in the same list:

```
modelName: Ember.computed(
  return this.get('modelName').map((o, i) => {
    return (i > 0 ? ' ' : '') + o.get('prop1') + '-' + o.get('prop2');
  });
})
```

My question is, where is the second computed property getting the comma to put in the comma-separated list? The initial code I tried was (i > 0 ? ', ' : '') but that was adding two commas. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to return the result.

```
modelName: Ember.computed('modelName',
  return this.get('modelName').map((o, i) => {
    return (i > 0 ? ' ' : '') + o.get('prop1') + '-' + o.get('prop2');
  });
})
```

and also I will encourage you to have dependant key `modelName`

Comment: It gives the same result with or without that return. The question I'm asking is where it gets the comma from.

Comment: When you do `{{arrayProperty}}` - then it will print it with comma separated by default. What do you want to acheive here ?.. you hve `{{#each` block to iterate it in hbs

Comment: I'm setting the computed property as a property of an ember-datatable defined using array-helper. The model being passed into the datatable hasMany modelNames, so they need to be made into a list like this to be passed into one field in the datatable. Maybe the array-helper component prints with commas by default as well. I'll look into it. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work without the return, that was a typo. I'll edit now.